# Not able to parse the json using jq

Tags: json, string, parsing, jq

I have following json with me ( file name sample.json)-

> {
>       "Prefix": "pg",
>       "fileFormat": "gz",
>       "additionalInfo":
>   "
>    {\"pgUsername\":\"postgres\",\"pgPassword\":\"postgres\",\"pgHostname\":\"pgmaster\"}"
>   }

I am reading these parameters using follwoing command-
`cat sample.json | jq -r '.additionalInfo .pgPassword'`

expected output is `postgres`, but I am getting something like `[26]`

I cant change this json. Does anyone knows, what command should be used to get correct output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is incorrect (you can verify in on https://jsonlint.com), you can try this one:

```
{
    "additionalInfo": {
        "pgUsername": "postgres",
        "pgPassword": "postgres",
        "pgHostname": "pgmaster"
    }
}
```

And you will get expected result:

```
$ cat data.json| jq -r '.additionalInfo .pgPassword'
postgres
```

---

EDIT

For your modified data you can use:

```
$ cat data.json| jq -r '.additionalInfo' | jq '.pgPassword'
postgres
```

---

EDIT AGAIN

Please, see a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461208/279355) by @peak -- it doesn't require multiple execution of `jq`, instead he proposes to use `fromjson` builtin.

Comment: I have some more fileds along with the previous one. So I have edited the question accordingly and also validated it on the link you provided.

Comment: It works!! Thanks for your quick update and quick reply. I really appreciate it. thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `fromjson`, there's no need to invoke jq twice:

```
jq -r '.additionalInfo|fromjson|.pgPassword' data.json
postgres
```

Comment: I didn't know about `fromjson` approach. You solution is much better, will mention that in my answer.